# Does the return type of a deleted operator matter if the operator is deleted?

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, deleted-functions

I am reading ‘C++ concurrency in action’, one page talks about copy-assignment operator =delete.

I have googled about it ([Deleting copy constructors and copy assignment operators. Which of them are essential?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33776697/deleting-copy-constructors-and-copy-assignment-operators-which-of-them-are-esse)) and tried some code by myself.

I want to know if there is a difference between

```
void operator= (const MyClass&) = delete;
```

and

```
MyClass& operator= (const MyClass&) = delete;
```

or I can just do

```
void operator= (MyClass) = delete;
```

It seems like it will "delete" the `operator =` anyway...

---

I just checked cppreference.com about Copy constructors and Copy assignment operator (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor)(https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment).

Could I just use the following code?

```
   MyClass(MyClass&)=delete;

   void operator= (MyClass) = delete;
```

I think it will "delete" everything anyway, so I don't need to worry about the "performance" of the copying, right?...

Comment: It works either way. A deleted operator is never going to return anything, so the return type is not important.

Comment: Most code nowadays prefer `MyClass& operator= (const MyClass&) = delete;` since an copy-assignment operator is to return a reference to itself

Comment: If some code (particularly template code) attempts to use the return value of the operator, having return type `void` could give additional compiler error messages, but the error about the deleted function is the useful one the programmer would want to look at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++ allows you to have operators with whatever return type you want.
In all cases, you are overloading `operator=` with different semantics so they will all work.
But it's best to follow the widespread convention of returning a class reference so that assignment chains (`a = b = c`) and constructs such as (`while ((a = b) == c) {...`) can work as well.

The second way you wrote:

```cpp
MyClass& operator=(const MyClass&) = delete;
```

is most used and as written, there is no need for a named parameter.

Comment: How would this chain "work" if the operator is deleted?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica It's not supposed to. I just said that if it's getting deleted, it doesn't matter what the operator='s semantics are so might as well follow the convention and then explained why that is the convention.  
It also seems that the question's title has been edited so maybe that's why my answer doesn't sound as clear.

Comment: Yes, my original title is written by my poor English...So it was changed a few...

I also want to know if I just want to save my typing code time and keep my codes concise, could I just use `void operator= (MyClass) = delete;` ? It will do the same job as the second way, right?

Comment: There is no need to worry about the performance because once the operator is removed, no copying will be done and all removals are the same. Saving coding time isn't always the best choice. People who are used to C++ expect the assignment operator to be written in the conventional form and it would look not-right seeing it return void. The parameter may or may not be a const reference depending on the class. For the copy-and-swap idiom, the operator's parameter is usually passed by value.